# How to find rows where the string is only different by 1 "word"?

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL, I have a single column table that has rows of **sentences**. I am trying to search for rows that are the exact same as a target sentence, but different by only 1 word.

Is this doable in SQL? Or do I have to programmatically load all the results and brute force my way down using other logic?

For example, my search term is Green T-Shirt Custom, the results should show:

```
Green T-Shirt Large
Green T-Shirt Small
```

Those 2 results work because it is different than my original sentence "Green T-Shirt Custom" by only 1 word.

Comment: try this `SELECT * FROM table where column like '%Green T-Shirt'`

Comment: Sorting results by "Levenshtein distance" might work. But better solution is to use MySQLfull text search.

Answer (score 2):

Basic SQL is not the best approach.  If you stored the sentences with one word per row and position in the sentence, then SQL would be more appropriate.

If you just wanted to match, say, the third word of three words, then you could do:

```
where substring_index(col, ' ', 2) = substring_index($target, ' ', 2)
```

However, this does not easily generalize.

Perhaps what you really want is full text search, which is amply described in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).  You can use double quotes around the search terms for an exact match . . . however, applying proximity and ordering with a missing word is challenging.

Answer (score 2):

Do a `like` for each search term. If 2 or more `like` are valid, return the row.

```
select * from tablename
where case when col like '%green%' then 1 else 0 end +
      case when col like '%t-shirt%' then 1 else 0 end +
      case when col like '%custom%' then 1 else 0 end >= 2
```

Note that the search term order doesn't matter here.

Comment: You can even use `col REGEXP '[[:<:]]green[[:>:]]'` to match against word boundaries.

Comment: @SalmanA, thanks for the tip! (I'm not a MySQL user, so I write ANSI SQL as far as possible.)

Answer (score 0):

You can search for strings with a fix number of missing chars with this syntax:

```
select * from usertable where name like 'M__e';
```

The '`_`' is a character of any kind, exactly and only one
The above query will return Mice, Maee but not Mali nor Maaae.

```
select * from usertable where name like 'M%e';
```

This returns all strings like Maae, but also Maaaaaaae or "Maaa bbbb e" with no restrictions on the length.